# require_once() error after moving Wordpressto another server

Tags: errors, migration

I got this type of error after moving Wordpress site to other server. I don't have mistakes in config and dont understand why this error occured?

Any suggestions to what might be causing these errors

```
Warning: require_once() [function.require-once]: 
Unable to access /public/sites/www.glasloodje.nl/wp-admin/includes/bookmark.php 
in /public/sites/www.glasloodje.nl/wp-admin/includes/admin.php on line 17

Warning: require_once(/public/sites/www.glasloodje.nl/wp-admin/includes/bookmark.php) 
[function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
in /public/sites/www.glasloodje.nl/wp-admin/includes/admin.php on line 17

Fatal error: require_once() 
[function.require]: Failed opening required 
'/public/sites/www.glasloodje.nl/wp-admin/includes/bookmark.php' 
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') 
in /public/sites/www.glasloodje.nl/wp-admin/includes/admin.php on line 17
```

Comment: So you have no activated plugins and only the default theme installed?

Comment: I have unziped the backup file of site.In test site it works well but when I move it to another hosting this cauues this errors.

Comment: I'm asking a last time: Have you _deactivated_ all plugins and the theme?

Comment: Yes of course.I deactivate all

Comment: To me it seems that either your options (site & blog url, etc.) are messed up or it's a hosting issue and you just uploaded it to the wrong path (relative to the public dir).

Comment: Sorry but all is correct I changed the url in database.In config file there is no mistake.I tried to move it to other hosting but there generally site didn't load.I cant imagine where is the problem..!I dont want to do all again.)

Comment: Why you have tagged `url-rewriting` tag?

Comment: Shot in the dark, but have you flushed your permalinks after the migration?

Answer (score 1):

Look towards the end of your **wp-config.php** file, you should have the definition for **ABSPATH** looking something like:

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

If it's a static path instead of the code above, then this might not correspond to your current path. Either change this to the code above or read on and try the other way to fix the issue:

To see exactly where your files are currently located in the new installation, place the following line right at the start of *index.php*, after the opening php tag:

```
<?php
die(dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

Now when you refresh the page, you should see the path and according to the error messages in your original post, it should be **/public/sites/www.glasloodje.nl** - if that's not the case, debug this or change the ABSPATH definition to:

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', '/absolute/path/that/shows/up/in/the/index.php/debug/message/');
```